# Pass struct to performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

Tags: objective-c, struct

I have a struct Position, like this:

```
typedef struct Position { int x, y; } Position;
```

How may I pass it in NSObject `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`? Like this:

```
Position pos;
pos.x = pos.y = 1;
[self performSelector:@selector(foo:)
           withObject:pos               // ERROR
           afterDelay:5.0f];
```

EDIT: changed code to fix typo

Answer (score 9):

Uhm.. use a CGPoint and something like

```
[self performSelector:@selector(foo:) 
           withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(pos.x, pos.y)] 
           afterDelay:5.0f];
```

And read it again as

```
NSValue v;
CGPoint point = [v CGPointValue];
```

or leave the Position class away completely, CGPoint does the same

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your custom type using `NSValue` class. The error is that you didn't provide an object reference to the method.

Try using `NSValue`'s `+(NSValue *)valueWithBytes:(const void *)value objCType:(const char *)type;` class method. On the other side you can retrieve the value using `-(void)getValue:(void *)buffer;`.

Answer (score 0):

`preformSelector:withObject:` accepts only objects as parameters, hence you'll have to implement your `foo:` method to accept an object. There are two ways to pass the struct as an object:

- create a struct-like object or
- wrap it into NSValue and unwrap it in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Full answer, based on user756245's (which doesn't tell you how to use it, not a great deal of help). Also, Apple suggests you use a slightly different method these days, IIRC:

```
typedef myStruct { int a; } myStruct;

myStruct aLocalPointer = ... assign to it

[self performSelector:@selector(myOtherMethod:) withObject:[NSValue value:&aLocalPointer withObjCType:@encode(myStruct)] afterDelay:0.25];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely asking for trouble, but you can pass `CGPoint` as `id` by bridging it in this way:

`withObject:(__bridge id)((void *)(&point))`

This will lead to a crash if `point` goes out of scope and your selector tries to read it, though.